# Whats the main problem with getting good multiple monitor support in ubuntu?

Tags: xorg, multiple-monitors

I mean what's keeping ubuntu from being as user-friendly as win7 in that regard. In win7 i can set up my laptops monitors and it remembers everything and undocking works etc etc. What technical problems(i assume its mostly technical) are there that are stopping this from happening in ubuntu? Whys an X restart needed? And please feel free to go into technical details.

Comment: The only situation I know where an X restart is needed is when the sum of all monitors resolution goes over the autodetected one, so you need a new X configuration. That's not normal, except for the first time. Is that what you're refering to?

Comment: You may wish to try the [Ubuntu Forums](http://ubuntuforums.org/) or [IRC](http://www.ubuntu.com/support/community) for questions of this nature (Discussion/Objective). For more information on questions which work best on this site see our [FAQ](http://askubuntu.com/faq)

Answer (score 0):

I never met some issues like this one, I have used many times  multiple monitors(2) to show how Ubuntu(karmic and Lucid) can handel it and all was clean. I didn't need any special configution tools behond "System-->Preferences-->Monitors"  I just pluged and played. May be the trouble are from an old edition of Ubuntu, I just tried with Karmic and Lucid